# hql select query on one to many relationship in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have one to many relationship between User and Country classes.
I am trying to get country's list based on username but facing `ClassCastExeption`

//User.java

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
private String username;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="username")
private Set<Country> countries;
//setters & getters
}
```

//Country.java

```
 @Entity
 public class Country {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;
//setters and getters
 }
```

//controller

```
  System.out.println(entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from country where username='Hussain'").getResultList().get(0) instanceof Country);
```

//output is false

I have tried creating Hql query as follows

```
  entityManager.createQuery("select c from Country c where c.username='Hussain'")
```

It is giving error like c.username not a property of Country class

thanks in adv.

Comment: why are you querying Country, instead of User? you have the list of countries in User entity.

Comment: To state the obvious ... c.username IS NOT A PROPERTY OF the Country class, so don't query for it. Look at your class! "username" is in User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hql needs to be

`from User u where u.username='Hussain'`

It will return user to you, and use

`user.getCountries()` to get countries.

More info: in real world, we usually set one country to many users.